# Cropping UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, crop

I have a view which needs to be cropped. I have 4 views displaying video sub viewed on the main view. Because of the videos ratio, I need to crop the views making the videos squares instead of rectangles. Here is my code:

```
- (void)videoSize {
    CGFloat size;
    if ([self.videosView frame].size.height <= [self.emplacementView frame].size.width) {
        size = [self.emplacementView frame].size.height;
    } else {
        size = [self.emplacementView frame].size.width;
    }
    CGFloat offsetX = 0;
    CGFloat offsetY = 0;

    NSArray* keys = [mediaStreams allKeys];
    int count = keys.count;
    if ( !count ) return;

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        NSString* id = keys[i];
        MediaStream* ms = [ mediaStreams valueForKey:id ];
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                offsetX = 0;
                offsetY = 0;
                break;
            case 1:
                offsetX = size / 2;
                offsetY = 0;
                break;
            case 2:
                offsetX = 0;
                offsetY = size / 2;
                break;
            case 3:
                offsetX = size / 2;
                offsetY = size / 2;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(offsetX, offsetY, size / 2, size / 2);
        [ms getVideoView].getView.frame = frame;
        [ms getVideoView].getView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    [self.videosView addSubview:[ [ mediaStream getVideoView ] getView] ];
}
```

I tried different ways by adding more views to hide them, but it doesn't work at all. If you already have a solution to this problem or an idea to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set clipsToBounds property for each of the 4 views displaying video to YES

```
view1.clipsToBounds = YES;
```